# Remove Woocommerce add to cart button from official shortcode loop

Tags: woocommerce

Currently I’m using this code here below to replace Add to cart feature with Read more link on the Woocommerce shop and loop pages. Now, if I am using official Woocommerce shortcodes to show products on the front page or any other places ([featruded_products] for example) then this code is not working.

How can I modify it to work on every loop but still work on the single product pages?

Thanks

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'disable_add_to_cart' );
 
function disable_add_to_cart() {
if ( is_shop() ) {
add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_purchasable', '__return_false');
} 
elseif ( is_product_category() ) {
add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_purchasable', '__return_false');
} 
}
```

Comment: Do you want to replace the text of the buttons or do you want to add a new link and text to the button as well?

Comment: I would like it to work as it does in Loop and Archive pages, that is makes it not purchasable and replace with Read more text.